# Does a x86 Dll work with X64 VB.NET?

Tags: c#, 64-bit

**I've been working around with a dll that was first created in a x32 version of C# 2010. Now, I installed Windows 7 x64 and C# on my PC.

The project works fine. I can edit all project forms but when I hit the debug button or the Compile button, it returns below error and shows "No source found".

```
BadImageFormatException
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem or if x64 is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a 32-bit assembly in 64-bit environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744284/use-a-32-bit-assembly-in-64-bit-environment)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot load a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit process.

Either change the DLL to AnyCPU, or change the EXE project to x86-only.

Comment: Problem is that on BUILD tab I only have AnyCPU mode  :(

Comment: That should not be true.  Show us a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You must change your platform to 32bit

[image]

If you cannot see the x86, select the `New...` option

[image]

select the x86 here:

[image]

Comment: No; you need Project Properties.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get Virtual Box, install in Virtual BOX a x32 Windows, and work in Virtual Box your project. After you done, save it to your machine  :)

X32 apps runs on x64